# Skype for business bot, need to send rest call to a server before replying

Tags: wpf, azure, botframework, ucma, ucwa

We are not migrated to Azure as of now, so not using MS Bot-Framework.

We are building an AI bot for skype for business. We already have our NLP modules (as REST api(s)) on a server. Now all we need is when a user ping our bot we need to get user message send the message to the server, which will return us the reply and put this reply back to the user.

basically to the user he is just ping a guy in the firm, while this guy/ bot/ profile, gets the automatic reply from a rest call.

Now though this looks simple, I am not sure what is the best way to do this out of:

- WPF controls
- Lync Client SDK
- UCWA
- UCMA
- Skype for Web SDK

I am quite new to this, and already alot confused.

Comment: Let's start with how will users get to your bot?  Is it part of a website or are they adding it as a Skype for Business contact and sending a message to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the best way to do this was UCMA.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn465943(v=office.16).aspx

And here is the sample code for the same

https://gist.github.com/AbhishekAshokDubey/110ebae9c48e4f5604c0feef13121cc2